# Why is row 8 conditional formatting showing an incorrect result?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using Excel 2019, I created a conditional formatting rule in J4 and applied it to J4:L9.  However, J8:L8 is clearly displaying incorrect formatting.  If I change A8 from zero to a '1', then row 8 is formatted correctly.  What's happening?

[image: Conditional Formatting Dialog]

[image: Spreadsheet with Incorrect Formatting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first formula `=$A4` is testing the value in that cell and not comparing it to the cell in `J4`.  Since you are using numbers, any number that is not `0` will return TRUE.  To test this you can change any of the "Matching" numbers in the J column to any other number and it will stay green:

***See J4***

[image]

So we need to actually spell out the comparison:

```
=J4 = $A4
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Also, it appears that I need to remove $ from $A4 so that K and L will look at the correct data.  hmmm.  I'm alternating three columns as groups of colors.  The next set of columns with this color formatting are P, Q, and R.  In between, I have three column groups with slightly bluer versions of green and red.  Will I need to recreate the conditional formatting for each group of three columns or is there a trick to allow all columns to receive the same conditional formatting rules?  And how do I stop it from messing with my border assignments?

Comment: New questions get new posts

Comment: ok.  I'll repost the second part.  However concerning A4, it appears that I need to remove $ from $A4 so that columns K and L will look at the correct columns and provide independent formatting?

Comment: Yes.  If your applies to includes those three columns then yes.